# How to search a given date value in all tables of present in database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I need a query to search for a particular date `2017-04-01` in every table in my database.

My database has many tables and I don't know in which table this value `2017-04-01` exists.

Please suggest a query which will help me to find the given date value in all the tables present in the database.

Datatype is **DATETIME**.

Comment: See Narayana Vyas's approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/436351/how-do-i-find-a-value-anywhere-in-a-sql-server-database

Answer (score 2):

You'll need to construct some dynamic T-SQL in order to search all columns in your database for a specific value.

Since you're searching for a `DATETIME` value, I've constructed the following example code which should point you in the right direction:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @FindText NVARCHAR(MAX) = 'CONVERT(DATETIME, ''2017-04-01 00:00:00.000'')';
DECLARE @cmd NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @deets NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Params NVARCHAR(MAX);
DECLARE @Name VARCHAR(1000);
DECLARE @Count INT;
DECLARE @RowNum INT;
SET @RowNum = 0;
SET @cmd = '';
SET @deets = '';
SET @Params = '@Name VARCHAR(1000) OUTPUT, @Count INT OUTPUT';

DECLARE cur CURSOR LOCAL FORWARD_ONLY STATIC
FOR
SELECT 'SELECT @Name = ''' + s.name + '.' + o.name + '.' + c.name + ''', @Count = COUNT(1) FROM ' + QUOTENAME(s.name) + '.' + QUOTENAME(o.name) + ' c WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = ' + @FindText + ' HAVING COUNT(1) > 0;'
    , 'SELECT * FROM ' + s.name + '.' + o.name + ' WHERE ' + QUOTENAME(c.name) + ' = ' + @FindText + ';'
FROM sys.schemas s WITH (NOLOCK)
    INNER JOIN sys.objects o WITH (NOLOCK) ON s.schema_id = o.schema_id
    INNER JOIN sys.columns c WITH (NOLOCK) ON o.object_id = c.object_id
    INNER JOIN sys.types t ON c.system_type_id = t.system_type_id
WHERE o.is_ms_shipped = 0
    AND o.type_desc = N'USER_TABLE'
    AND s.name <> N'sys' --ignore the sys schema
    AND t.name IN ( --could eliminate all but datetime if certain!
          'date'
        , 'datetime2'
        , 'datetimeoffset'
        , 'smalldatetime'
        , 'datetime'
    );

OPEN cur;
FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd, @deets;
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
    --PRINT N'RowNum:' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @RowNum);
    SET @Name = NULL;
    SET @Count = NULL;
    EXEC sp_executesql @cmd, @Params, @Name = @Name OUT, @Count = @Count OUT;
    IF @Count > 0 PRINT @Name + ': ' + CONVERT(VARCHAR(50), @Count) + '                            ' + @deets;
    SET @RowNum = @RowNum + 1;
    FETCH NEXT FROM cur INTO @cmd, @deets;
END
CLOSE cur;
DEALLOCATE cur;
```

Since this type of code can be susceptible to code-injection vulnerabilities, I'd never recommend using this in a stored procedure, or any code that is called by code where a user can enter the value for `@FindText`.  See ["little bobby tables"](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=little+bobby+tables&t=ffsb) for details about that.